# When Will Python support be added in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

When will Hyperledger Fabric add support for Python Language and Support for raspberry pi for IoT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hyperledger Sawtooth supports Python, as does Hyperledger Iroha. But my guess is you are referring to Hyperledger Fabric, so I edited your question to avoid confusion.

That said, remember that Python is good for rapid development and deployment.  It has performance problems being an interpretive language and not allowing multiple threads to execute at the same time (due to it's global "GIL" lock restricting execution to 1 thread at-a-time).

Comment: Thanks, i was looking for fabric only. I guesd i have to roll on other ones.

Answer (score 1):

There is an incubating project for an sdk in python, you can have a look at it.
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-py
It does not look very active and on their Jira board there is nothing:
https://jira.hyperledger.org/secure/RapidBoard.jspa?rapidView=85&projectKey=FAB&view=detail

But there is some activity, so don't lose hope.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.